# I want to hook GetQueuedCompletionStatus in kernel32.dll, but it seems to not exist in the IAT table

Tags: c++, windows

I want to hook `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` in `kernel32.dll`, but it seems to not exist in the IAT table. I print all of the function names in `OriginalFirstThunk` list, but I do not find `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()`. There are dozens of functions, but as I know, `kernel32.dll` supports over a hundred functions. Why? Where are they?

The log is:

```
[2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name ResumeThread     
00000763    6.80356741  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetThreadContext     
00000764    6.80357981  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name SetThreadContext     
00000765    6.80359268  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name VirtualQuery     
00000766    6.80360556  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetCurrentProcess    
00000767    6.80361938  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name InterlockedCompareExchange   
00000768    6.80363131  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetCurrentThread     
00000769    6.80364466  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name FlushInstructionCache    
00000770    6.80365753  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name VirtualAlloc     
00000771    6.80366945  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name VirtualProtect   
00000772    6.80368328  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetCurrentThreadId   
00000773    6.80369616  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name SuspendThread    
00000774    6.80370951  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name SetLastError     
00000775    6.80372143  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetFileSize  
00000776    6.80373430  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name WriteFile    
00000777    6.80374718  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name CloseHandle  
00000778    6.80376005  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name HeapReAlloc  
00000779    6.80377293  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name FindResourceExW  
00000780    6.80378580  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name FindResourceW    
00000781    6.80379820  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name FreeLibrary  
00000782    6.80381107  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name LoadResource     
00000783    6.80382490  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name HeapAlloc    
00000784    6.80383921  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name HeapFree     
00000785    6.80385208  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetModuleHandleW     
00000786    6.80386496  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetProcessHeap   
00000787    6.80387783  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetPrivateProfileStringW     
00000788    6.80389023  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name LoadLibraryW     
00000789    6.80390310  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount    
00000790    6.80391598  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name SizeofResource   
00000791    6.80392981  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name HeapDestroy  
00000792    6.80394220  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetModuleFileNameW   
00000793    6.80395508  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name RaiseException   
00000794    6.80396795  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetProcAddress   
00000795    6.80398083  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name HeapSize     
00000796    6.80399370  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name LoadLibraryA     
00000797    6.80400658  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name LockResource     
00000798    6.80401850  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name DecodePointer    
00000799    6.80403137  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name DeleteCriticalSection    
00000800    6.80404568  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetTempPathW     
00000801    6.80406141  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetFileAttributesW   
00000802    6.80407429  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name CreateFileW  
00000803    6.80408812  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name ReadFile     
00000804    6.80410242  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name SetEnvironmentVariableW  
00000805    6.80411530  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetSystemDirectoryW  
00000806    6.80412865  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetVersionExW    
00000807    6.80414820  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name LocalFree    
00000808    6.80416059  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name Sleep    
00000809    6.80417347  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name WritePrivateProfileStringW   
00000810    6.80418634  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name MultiByteToWideChar  
00000811    6.80419922  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetCurrentProcessId  
00000812    6.80421257  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetLocalTime     
00000813    6.80422497  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name SetEnvironmentVariableA  
00000814    6.80423832  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetEnvironmentVariableA  
00000815    6.80425119  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetModuleHandleA     
00000816    6.80426502  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetModuleFileNameA   
00000817    6.80427837  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetCommandLineW  
00000818    6.80429220  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetTickCount     
00000819    6.80430555  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name RemoveDirectoryW     
00000820    6.80431938  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name CreateDirectoryW     
00000821    6.80433178  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name SetUnhandledExceptionFilter  
00000822    6.80434465  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name SetErrorMode     
00000823    6.80435753  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name TerminateProcess     
00000824    6.80436945  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name AllocConsole     
00000825    6.80438328  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name SetCurrentDirectoryW     
00000826    6.80439615  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetEnvironmentVariableW  
00000827    6.80440903  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name LoadLibraryExA   
00000828    6.80442095  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name OutputDebugStringA   
00000829    6.80443430  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetPrivateProfileIntW    
00000830    6.80444717  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name InterlockedDecrement     
00000831    6.80446005  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetSystemDefaultLangID   
00000832    6.80447292  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetUserDefaultLangID     
00000833    6.80448580  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name UnregisterWaitEx     
00000834    6.80449820  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name QueryDepthSList  
00000835    6.80451107  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name InterlockedFlushSList    
00000836    6.80452394  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name InterlockedPushEntrySList    
00000837    6.80453682  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name InterlockedPopEntrySList     
00000838    6.80454969  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name InitializeSListHead  
00000839    6.80456305  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name ReleaseSemaphore     
00000840    6.80457592  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name VirtualFree  
00000841    6.80458879  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name FreeLibraryAndExitThread     
00000842    6.80460167  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetLastError     
00000843    6.80461454  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name ReadConsoleW     
00000844    6.80462742  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name SetStdHandle     
00000845    6.80463982  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name WriteConsoleW    
00000846    6.80465269  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetThreadTimes   
00000847    6.80466557  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name OutputDebugStringW   
00000848    6.80467844  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name FreeEnvironmentStringsW  
00000849    6.80469179  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetEnvironmentStringsW   
00000850    6.80470467  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name QueryPerformanceCounter  
00000851    6.80471659  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name FlushFileBuffers     
00000852    6.80472946  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name SetFilePointerEx     
00000853    6.80474234  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetConsoleMode   
00000854    6.80475616  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetConsoleCP     
00000855    6.80476809  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name UnregisterWait   
00000856    6.80478096  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name RegisterWaitForSingleObject  
00000857    6.80479431  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetOEMCP     
00000858    6.80480719  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetACP   
00000859    6.80482006  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name IsValidCodePage  
00000860    6.80483294  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetFileType  
00000861    6.80484581  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetStdHandle     
00000862    6.80485821  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name AreFileApisANSI  
00000863    6.80487108  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name SetEndOfFile     
00000864    6.80488300  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name CompareStringW   
00000865    6.80489588  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name LCMapStringW     
00000866    6.80490875  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetLocaleInfoW   
00000867    6.80492163  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name IsValidLocale    
00000868    6.80493593  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name WideCharToMultiByte  
00000869    6.80494881  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetModuleHandleExW   
00000870    6.80496168  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name ExitProcess  
00000871    6.80497456  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name EnumSystemLocalesW   
00000872    6.80498743  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name DuplicateHandle  
00000873    6.80499983  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetSystemTimeAsFileTime  
00000874    6.80501270  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetStringTypeW   
00000875    6.80502558  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name EncodePointer    
00000876    6.80503941  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name EnterCriticalSection     
00000877    6.80506563  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name LeaveCriticalSection     
00000878    6.80507898  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name IsDebuggerPresent    
00000879    6.80509281  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name IsProcessorFeaturePresent    
00000880    6.80510569  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetCPInfo    
00000881    6.80511904  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name CreateTimerQueue     
00000882    6.80513668  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name UnhandledExceptionFilter     
00000883    6.80514956  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name CreateEventW     
00000884    6.80516243  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name TlsAlloc     
00000885    6.80517530  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name TlsGetValue  
00000886    6.80518818  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name TlsSetValue  
00000887    6.80520058  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name TlsFree  
00000888    6.80521345  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetStartupInfoW  
00000889    6.80522633  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name CreateSemaphoreW     
00000890    6.80523920  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name CreateThread     
00000891    6.80525208  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name ExitThread   
00000892    6.80526495  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name LoadLibraryExW   
00000893    6.80527782  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name RtlUnwind    
00000894    6.80529022  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name SetEvent     
00000895    6.80530310  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name WaitForSingleObjectEx    
00000896    6.80531597  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name SignalObjectAndWait  
00000897    6.80532885  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name SwitchToThread   
00000898    6.80534172  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name SetThreadPriority    
00000899    6.80535460  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetThreadPriority    
00000900    6.80536699  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetLogicalProcessorInformation   
00000901    6.80537987  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name CreateTimerQueueTimer    
00000902    6.80539274  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name ChangeTimerQueueTimer    
00000903    6.80540562  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name DeleteTimerQueueTimer    
00000904    6.80541849  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetNumaHighestNodeNumber     
00000905    6.80543041  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetProcessAffinityMask   
00000906    6.80544329  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name SetThreadAffinityMask    
00000907    6.80545616  [2532] 2532: 16508: DingTalk.exe _IATHook_Single func name GetUserDefaultLCID
```

Comment: I think I got the reason.  The IAT just contain the function the process used.  I hook the function in a dll, and the main process doesn't use GetQueuedCompletionStatus() at all, so it not exist in IAT. Thanks all.

Comment: That just means the app is not linking to `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` *statically*. It might be loaded *dynamically* at runtime instead, via `GetProcAddress()` (either explicitly, or via [delay loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls)). In that case, you would have to hook `GetProcAddress()` first (or use a [delay-load notification hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/error-handling-and-notification)) to discover `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` so you can then hook it.

Comment: I got it. Very helpful. Thank you very much